# MySQL priorities

Tags: mysql, performance

Is it possible to se priorities in MySQL?

On one server I have application that receives data from or primary server and store it to DB for further use. On the other side I have website and Phone APPs. What I would like to do is set priority to users (web and phone) to ensure that they will always have better access. Data can take much more time since it is done by crontab.

Comment: Are you saying I'm slow?!  ;)

Comment: :) no I am just saying you have time ;)

Comment: Unfortunately MySQL has no concept of priorities. What do you mean by "I have application that receives data from or primary server and store it to DB"? Could you explain exactly what this process is doing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to set [account resource limits](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/user-resources.html), but these don't set a priority as such. Instead, they allow you to limit the number of connections/queries/updates for each user on the database.

You might be able to use [mysql-proxy](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-proxy/en/) to do something a little more custom. It can be customised by a lua script, which would allow you to introduce some more specific behaviour like blocking a query if the server is too busy etc..

Answer (score 1):

You can dynamically set the [low_priority_updates](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_low_priority_updates) system variable at time of query.  It will prioritize SELECT statements over INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE statements.  Though this won't work if you're using InnoDB tables.